# Nvidia visual profiler not showing cudaMalloc() after kernel launch

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust, dynamic-parallelism

I am trying to write a program that runs almost entirely on the GPU (with very little interaction with the host). `initKernel` is the first kernel that is being launched from the host. I use Dynamic parallelism to launch successive kernels from the `initKernel`, two of which are `thrust::sort(thrust::device,...)`.

[image]

Before launching the `initKernel`, I do a `cudaMalloc()` on the host code and it is shown in the *Runtime API* of the Visual profiler. None of the `cudaMalloc`s that appear in the `__device__` functions and successive kernels (after the launch of `initKernel`) are shown in the *Runtime API* of the Visual profiler. Can someone help me understand why I cannot see the `cudaMalloc`s in the Visual profiler?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone help me understand why I cannot see the cudaMallocs in the Visual profiler?

Because it is a documented limitation of the tool.  From the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#profiler-known-issues):

> The Visual Profiler timeline does not display CUDA API calls invoked from within device-launched kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you suggest a tip (or technique) to identify such cudaMalloc() related hotspots? For example, when I use thrust::sort() from the device, I realize that on every call to that thrust::sort() kernel, cudaMalloc() is being called to allocate a large temporary buffer. Is there a way to find out the time taken by these particular cudaMallocs when thrust::sort() is called from the device code?

Comment: both thrust and cub provide for the possibility of using your own allocator.  It's mandatory for cub, and optional for thrust.  If you don't like the `cudaMalloc` behavior of thrust, you could investigate using thrust with a custom allocator or just using cub for device code sorting.  I don't know of a way to make device API cudaMalloc appear in the visual profiler timeline, just like I don't know of a way to make any other device level instruction appear.  You can use [PC sampling](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#pc-sampling) to get an idea, however.

Comment: Yes, I investigated the use of a custom allocator in thrust::sort(), a couple of days ago. The examples concerning custom allocator that I find on the internet give me several compile time errors (when integrated in my Visual Studio project). Apparently, it is not that straightforward. I cannot use cub as I need to sort an array of structs. Thanks for the link.